# Can't make arithmetic operator precedence with parenthesis in bison

Tags: c, bison, arithmetic-expressions

I've currently building a Python parser and I'm at the definition of arithmetic expressions. The rules behind arithmetic expressions are working properly up until I add the parenthesis.

Here is the starting point:

```
%token TOKEN_ARITH_ADD TOKEN_ARITH_SUB
%token TOKEN_ARITH_MUL TOKEN_ARITH_DIV TOKEN_ARITH_MOD
%token TOKEN_ARITH_POWER
%token TOKEN_ASSIGN
%token TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN TOKEN_PAREN_CLOSE
```

and then:

```
arith_expr: factor
    | arith_expr TOKEN_ARITH_ADD factor { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "+", $1); };
    | arith_expr TOKEN_ARITH_SUB factor { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "-", $1); };
    | TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN arith_expr TOKEN_PAREN_CLOSE { $$ = $2; };
;

factor: power { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($1, NULL, NULL); };
    | factor TOKEN_ARITH_MUL power { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "*", $1); };
    | factor TOKEN_ARITH_DIV power { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "/", $1); };
    | factor TOKEN_ARITH_MOD power { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "%", $1); };
;

power: term
    | power TOKEN_ARITH_POWER term { $$ = ast_init_arith_op($3, "**", $1); }

term: identifier;
    | literal_int;
    | literal_float;
```

The results is that if, for instance, I enter this :

```
myVar = (a + b) * 2
```

I get `error: syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_ARITH_MUL, expecting TOKEN_EOL`.

So I've tried to change the `%token` for `%left` for the first three ones, with the same problem.

I've also tried to change the `%token` for the assign to a `%right`, unfortunately I got an error at compile time (`error: rule given for assign, which is a token`) - in retrospect, make sense.

It looks like the `TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN arith_expr TOKEN_PAREN_CLOSE` collapse to a `arith_expr` and the `assign` kicks in right away. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You add that parens rule in the wrong place (at the lowest precedence level instead of the highest you need). Remove and add to the rules for `term`.

Comment: I'm not sure, term is like an identifier (lets say myVar), a integer literal and or a float literal. If I put the ` | TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN term TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN { $$ = $2 }; };` there, I can't have a arithmetic expression between the parenthesis (only a term). So for instance : `myVar = (a + b)` gives me `syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_ARITH_ADD, expecting TOKEN_PAREN_CLOSE`

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html and how the precedence levels stack starting with primary_expression. I know it's possible to achieve precedence disambiguation purely through use of %left/%right/%nonassoc but I find the organization style of that C grammar much easier to follow than one that lumps everything under a single non-terminal. (Although I am given to understand one that does use only one non-terminal will be more efficient at run-time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your grammar, a multiplication operator can appear only between a `factor` and a `power`.  An expression enclosed in parentheses is neither and cannot be reduced to either.  As far as the part of the grammar presented goes, it is an `arith_expr`.

@n.m.'s comment is correct: you put the rule for a parenthesized expression in the wrong place.  It should be a `term`, not an `arith_expr`.  However, your followup comment suggests that you misunderstood.  Do not change the production. Just move it, as is, to be one of the alternatives for `term`:

```
term: identifier
    | literal_int
    | literal_float
    | TOKEN_PAREN_OPEN arith_expr TOKEN_PAREN_CLOSE
;
```

That allows a parenthsized expression to appear as a complete expression itself or as an operand of any operator.